# Hibernate loading object immediately after create

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, orm, persistence

I have a Hibernate entity which has one or more `<many-to-one` mappings, e.g.

```
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="MyClass" table="my_table">
    <cache usage="nonstrict-read-write"/>
      <composite-id>
        <key-property name="id" length="30"/>
        <key-property name="someRef" length="30" column="foreign_key_to_something"/>
      </composite-id>
    <many-to-one name="mappedProperty" column="foreign_key_to_something" insert="false" update="false"/>
    <property name="foo" column="foo"/>
    ...
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I need to create such an entity and get immediate access to `mappedProperty` after the creation. I can see two approaches here:

1) Create the entity and set all related `<many-to-one` mappings manually. The obvious disadvantage of this approach is the legwork required, especially if the amount of mapped `<many-to-one` entities is high. Why do something manually if framework can do it for you?

2) Create the entity by only initializing necessary parameters (e.g. primary keys, `id` and `someRef` in the above case), then save and re-load it immediately. Loading should initialize the `mappedProperty` automatically or provide lazy initialization on demand.

I prefer option 2), however, I have noticed that in some cases, `mappedProperty` property is not set. `load()` returns the same same object I passed to `create()`, only having primary keys initialized. I am still not sure why this happens, but to fight it I'd have to detach the object from the Hibernate session so the `load()` would be forced to go to the database and get anew. Again, sounds quite overcomplicated, doesn't it?

Am I missing something here? Are there any other ways to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you need to refresh state of the object from the database, use `refresh()`.

Comment: Note: if anyone else will use this approach, don't forget to do `session.flush()` before `refresh()`. For more details, see: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=982332&view=next

Answer (score 1):

`load` and `get` return the object from the session if it's already there. Your second option would thus need you to flush, then remove the entity from the session, then reload it (issuing a select query for data you know). A call to refresh would do the same, more easily, but would still issue an additional select query for nothing.

I really prefer the first option : just make sure that each time the association is set, then the corresponding mapped property is mapped as well. You're responsible for the coherence and invariants of the entities (as with bidirectional associations, where both sides must be maintained).

A third option would be to remove the mapped property completely, and simply call entity.getKey().getSomeRef().getId().

Comment: Thanks, but as I said - the first option is really awkward to work with if your entity has multiple mappings. Some of my entities have around 10 dependant entities and setting them all would be a nightmare :(